# missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I get these errors when I compile this. I can not find out the error. Specially why `;` is required and why function templates are already defined. I am using Visual Studio 2010. This works with **Turbo C++** but I want to know why these errors comes with **Visual C++**.

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'file'    
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'file'    
Error   10  error C2995: 'int FileOperations<T>::getNoOfElements(void)' : function template has already been defined    
Error   9   error C2995: 'T FileOperations<T>::readFromFile(int)' : function template has already been defined  
Error   8   error C2995: 'void FileOperations<T>::swriteToFile(T,int)' : function template has already been defined 
Error   7   error C2995: 'void FileOperations<T>::writeToFile(T)' : function template has already been defined  
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

#ifndef FileOp_h
#define FileOp_h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

template <class T>
class FileOperations
{
    private:
        fstream file;


    public:
        FileOperations(){};

        FileOperations(const char* fileName){fileOpen(fileName);};

        void fileOpen(const char* fileName){file.open(fileName,ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::binary);};

        void writeToFile(T);
        void swriteToFile(T,int);
        T readFromFile(int);
        int getNoOfElements();

        ~FileOperations(){file.close();};

};

#endif

template <class T>
void FileOperations<T>::writeToFile(T fileOb)
{
    file.clear();
    file.write((char*)&fileOb, sizeof(fileOb))<<flush;
}

template <class T>
void FileOperations<T>::swriteToFile(T fileOb,int seekTo)
{
    file.clear();
    file.seekp(seekTo,ios::beg);
    file.write((char*)&fileOb, sizeof(fileOb))<<flush;
}

template <class T>
T FileOperations<T>::readFromFile(int seekTo)
{
    T object;
    file.seekg(seekTo,ios::beg);
    file.read((char*)&object,sizeof(object));
    file.clear();
    return object;
}

template <class T>
int FileOperations<T>::getNoOfElements()
{
    file.seekg(0,ios::end);
    int size=file.tellg();
    return size/sizeof(T);
}
```

Comment: I got the answer for the first one. It is becaused I havent used the namespace. Now I want to know why does it say function templates are already defined. How do i resolve this

Comment: There is no need of `;` here. `FileOperations(){};`. You are doing that in quite a few places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say `std::fstream file;` instead of `fstream file;`, because `fstream` is declared in the Standard namespace `std`, not in the global namespace.

In the `.cpp` file corresponding to `FileOp.h` you may choose to say `using namespace std;` in that `.cpp` file if you don't want to type `std::` everywhere in that file (it's basically a question of taste and how likely you want to be to get name conflicts. Making all names of `std::` unqualified visible increases the likelihood of name conflicts with global names). But don't put such a line into a header.

Since your code appears to be entirely into one `.h` file you won't have such an option then. But you can locally in the member functions say `using namespace std;` or declare individual names as aliases in local scope of member functions, like `using std::fstream;`, if you want.

Also, you need to put the definition of those member functions (of the class template) *within* the header guard, if not directly within the class body if you like. Your other error messages appear because you include the header multiple times, but the member function definitions, appearing outside the header guard, wrongly will be emitted into the translation unit multiple times, raising multiple definition errors at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I figured it out. I used the name space now it does not give that error but it still gives Error   10  error C2995: 'int FileOperations<T>::getNoOfElements(void)' : function template has already been defined    
Error   9   error C2995: 'T FileOperations<T>::readFromFile(int)' : function template has already been defined  
Error   8   error C2995: 'void FileOperations<T>::swriteToFile(T,int)' : function template has already been defined 

 errors. Can you tell me what is the reason for that...?

Comment: Can you show me the piece of cord for the last issue. How to put the definitions in to the header guard. Please

Comment: I mean in my code where to put it. Anyway thanks for the help so far. I tried to find how to put it inside the header guard. But i coldn't find it yet. Anyway if it is not possible it is ok. I will try some how to find it.. Thanks for the great help...

Comment: Got it bro. I put the whole member functions in side the class it self. Now I am finding the way to do it other way around. And some one please tell me what is the header guard

Comment: @Gihan You should have asked about the header guard first! The header guard is that `#ifndef`/`#define` thing you put at the beginning. (https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: Sorry It was a communication mistake.The issue is bro I don't know the exact words what do we call in side the code. My stupidity. I think header guard it #ifndef FileOp_h
#define FileOp_h #endif right...!! It worked when I put the #endif at the end also....Thanks Alot people. Finally all figured out.....Sorry if i irritate you guys by asking effortless questions. It wont happen again